# Flutter InAppWebView showing blank page on release mode

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello experts i am using InAppWebView plugin for loading web from the assets folder when i run it on debug mode its working fine when used release mode app show blank page any expert know this issue i am trying find there solution everywhere but no solution fine if any friend can help i will appreciate him?

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
    
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
    
    
    
      final String title;
    
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    late  InAppWebViewController webView;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
    
            title: Text('Tic Tac Toe'),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
     Expanded(
       child: InAppWebView(
                  initialFile: "assets/TicTacToe.html",
                  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                    webView = controller;
                  },
    
                ),
     ),
            ],
    
          ),
    
        );
    
      }
    
    
    
    
    }
Syncing files to device RMX2020...
I/GED     (14959): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 24, oppidx_max 24, oppidx_min 0
I/BufferQueue(14959): [unnamed-14959-0](this:0x75cf2bb000,id:0,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) BufferQueue core=(14959:com.tictac.toe.fivverproject)
E/libc    (14959): Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump"
I/BufferQueueConsumer(14959): [unnamed-14959-0](this:0x75cf2bb000,id:0,api:0,p:-1,c:14959) connect(C): consumer=(14959:com.tictac.toe.fivverproject) controlledByApp=true
E/libc    (14959): Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump"
I/BufferQueueConsumer(14959): [unnamed-14959-0](this:0x75cf2bb000,id:0,api:0,p:-1,c:14959) setConsumerName: unnamed-14959-0
W/e.fivverproject(14959): type=1400 audit(0.0:854881): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:debug_bq_dump_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=117 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c39,c258,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debug_bq_dump_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/libc    (14959): Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump"
I/BufferQueueConsumer(14959): [SurfaceTexture-0-14959-0](this:0x75cf2bb000,id:0,api:0,p:-1,c:14959) setConsumerName: SurfaceTexture-0-14959-0
I/BufferQueueConsumer(14959): [SurfaceTexture-0-14959-0](this:0x75cf2bb000,id:0,api:0,p:-1,c:14959) setDefaultBufferSize: width=720 height=1336
I/BufferQueueProducer(14959): [SurfaceTexture-0-14959-0](this:0x75cf2bb000,id:0,api:1,p:723,c:14959) connect(P): api=1 producer=(723:???) producerControlledByApp=false
W/Gralloc3(14959): allocator 3.x is not supported
E/ion     (14959): ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
D/BufferQueueProducer(14959): [SurfaceTexture-0-14959-0](this:0x75cf2bb000,id:0,api:1,p:723,c:14959) cancelBuffer: slot 0
D/BufferQueueProducer(14959): [SurfaceTexture-0-14959-0](this:0x75cf2bb000,id:0,api:1,p:723,c:14959) cancelBuffer: slot 0
D/BufferQueueProducer(14959): [SurfaceTexture-0-14959-0]
```

(this:0x75cf2bb000,id:0,api:1,p:723,c:14959) cancelBuffer: slot 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I face the same problem you may need to put network permission for android:

```
<manifest xmlns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

see this:https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/networking